# Setting form element from jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, struts2, action

There is a Jsp form, in which I have an input field, called height.
There is a modal dialog, which was being created by jquery.
form:

`<form action="paths" id="paths_form" name="defaultcheck">
<input id="height" name="height" value="" type="text"/>`

dialog:

```
          $(function() {
            $( "#parcel" ).dialog({
              buttons: {
               "Ok": function() {                     
                   $('#height').val("test");
                                 }
                })}
               });
```

I need to set the value of height from the dialog, using jquery. When I submit the form in jsp page, I want that height value in action class.

I am getting height as 0 in action class.(I have created getter and setter methods also).

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AleksandrM Sir, I have edited my question, added my code. Let me know for more info.

Comment: What is not working? Setting value in js? Sending to server?

Comment: @AleksandrM Sir, I have set the value from dialog box and trying to use the value in action class, It is not getting the value. It is displaying null value.

Comment: Show your form and action. Are you setting `height` value to `test`? And what type is `height`? A number?

Comment: @AleksandrM Sir, Height is String type. Yeah, I am setting height value as "test".

Comment: I have found the solution sir, @AleksandrM, I have made another separate field inside the form and updating that value from dialog box, on user selection criteria.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it to help future visitors with similar problem.